# Gradle: Comparing maven and gradle artifacts built from the same source

Tags: java, maven, gradle

There's an incubating feature in gradle for comparing builds (documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/comparing_builds.html)). The documentation states it can compare:

> A Gradle build with a build executed by another tool such as Apache Ant, Apache Maven or something else (i.e. migrating to Gradle).

I'd like to use this feature but the documentation doesn't outline how to do it. I'd like to build the same source code twice, once with maven then with gradle and compare the built artifact (a jar).

I've generated a build.gradle using `gradle-init --type pom` now i'd like to

1. Run the gradle build (build.gradle)
2. Run the maven build (pom.xml)
3. Compare the jars built by both

I don't mind if I need two duplicate copies of the source code to achieve this. I'd like to automate the process so that it's repeatable as I migrate my build from maven to gradle.